# Java produce xml version 1.1

Tags: java, xml, sax

I have a xml file which has the following header: `<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. It is also mandatory, that this file is version 1.1 since there are some characters included, which are not allowed in version 1.1.

My task is to extract some entities from the file and save it again as xml file. If I produce a new xml file, it will be in version 1.0. Since there are some encoding errors in the new file, I assume the problem is the wrong xml version. Is there a possibility to produce a xml file in version 1.1 (including the correct header)?

Here is a snippet of my current code:

```
//read the file
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
...
}

//write the output file
SAXTransformerFactory fac = (SAXTransformerFactory)TransformerFactory.newInstance();
final TransformerHandler tfh = fac.newTransformerHandler();
Transformer transformer = tfh.getTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Best,
Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to specify the version as an output property.

See [OutputKeys.VERSION](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html#VERSION).